# 2 year old has very runny stuffy nose for 4 months

Tags: toddler, health

My 2 year old has runny nose for 4 months. Doctor says 1 time its cold, another time its allergy, but nothing clear. Tylenol doesn't help and i really can't believe that cold can be 4 months. She can't breath and I thought its simple allergy, but ceterezin and benadril don't help also. Mucus is non stop running, not clear , like solid white color and like plastic very sticky, impossible to clean her nose. I can give her Tylenol, Benadryl, wash her nose with the whole bottle of saline and in 2 sec in will be the same runny stuffy nose. Its way too long and. I am so scared what to do?
I have never seen anything like that in my life!!

Comment: Take your child to a doctor.

Comment: @MiaClarke - They did and have had a range of answers, none of them clear.  Though you're right that further investigation is needed.

Comment: As the two community members comment above, the best way to get help is to see a doctor.  Make sure to let the doctor know how long the nose has been running and if yet another opinion is needed to find an answer, keep trying.  We simply can't diagnose what is going on, online.

Answer (score 4):

None of the medications you are giving to your child address the problem s/he is suffering from. All they do is help manage the symptoms, sometimes by suppressing them.

Is your child at kindergarden? It is not uncommon for such children to *constantly* have a runny nose. In fact, they *constantly* pick up infections from each other, so what seems like a constant runny nose is more likely a continuous sequence of runny noses.

Do you have pets at home? Perhaps your child is allergic. Then the solution is not to pump the child full of medicine, but, unfortunately, to find another home for the pet.

Ultimately, really the best bet is to get your doctor to refer you to a specialist. *Insist that you be referred to a specialist.*

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I could not do anything as she had runny nose 24/7 and I do believe it was allergic reaction on something but not sure what. I use only Method cleaning supplies and no pets allowed. I clean the house everyday by myself to make sure that everything is cleaned. No Clorox or other bad stuff. What I did to resolve the issue: I got in a car and crossed the country. We lived in Florida and now we are in California. The more we were driving the more my baby could breath.

Comment: We are vegan so she really is healthy,but she got sick and she has runny nose fir over a week now and I am scared to think that its something else, but a cold. I have never seen anything like this before, she had a wet face that you just can't ever wipe.  Its much better now, but scares me that its so long. Does anyone know if simply cold can be that long . Thank you!!

Comment: @Nana (On moving to California from Florida) that sounds like an allergy to something that's specific to the Florida-region. That, or coincedence. Are the move and clean nose permanent?

Answer (score 3):

Any 'cold' that doesn't clear up in a short time usually means an allergic reaction to something..Go to your doctor and ask for a referral to an allergy specialist For peace of mind for you, the parent,write down clearly, what your child presents with and when and the frequency..

Answer (score 1):

I have severe, year-round allergies.  The thing about allergies is you have to repeat the treatments every 12 hours at most.  Some drugs are more like 4 hours.  You're just suppressing the symptoms, not fixing the underlying cause.  As soon as you stop the treatment, the symptoms come back.

Also, even with treatment, you still get congestion.  A decongestant will dry you out, but those are only recommended for short term, like during a cold.  The other drugs will usually make the congestion smaller and less uncomfortable, but not take it away.  You just have to get used to blowing it all out several times per day.  Two year-olds are not very good at this.

Also, different drugs work better or worse on different kinds of allergies.  Most over-the-counter drugs work best on seasonal outdoor allergies, like pollen, where you only need them for a couple months every Spring.

You really need to see an allergy specialist.  He will be able to prescribe a course of treatment that fits your daughter's individual circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

My lad always had a runny nose and trouble breathing, he seemed continuously sick. It turned out to be over-sized adenoids/tonsils. It took a long time for a doctor to mention his breathing issues. This is probably because you only take a kid to a doctor when they are sick, so the doctor assumes the tonsils are enlarged because they are inflamed. Adenoids cannot be seen by a GP.

Does the child snore excessively when she sleeps?
Any trouble hearing?
Is the child sleepy?